# MongoDB difference between sort in aggregation and find

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have one complex query, it contains few "stages" (match, sort, offset, limit), but when I execute it in aggregation pipeline it takes 10 minutes, but in find(...).skip.limit.sort it takes just 0.5 seconds, why it works so?

Additional information:
Collection size: 20 000 000
Storage size: 33GB
Indexes: 16
Avg document size: 6kb
Document have complex structure with a lot of internal objects and arrays.

match/find stage example (all fields in query are indexed):

```
{
  "Target._id":{
    "$in":[
      CSUUID("73aedf6b-dba7-4905-5187-08d7d623e1a0")
    ]
  },
  "StartDateTime":{
    "$gte":ISODate("2020-03-31T21:00:00Z"),
    "$lte":ISODate("9999-12-30T22:00:00Z")
  },
  "$expr":{
    "$switch":{
      "branches":[
        {
          "case":{
            "$and":[
              {
                "$gte":[
                  "$StartDateTime",
                  ISODate("2020-03-31T21:00:00Z")
                ]
              },
              {
                "$lte":[
                  "$StartDateTime",
                  ISODate("9999-12-30T22:00:00Z")
                ]
              },
              {
                "$in":[
                  "$Target._id",
                  [
                    CSUUID("73aedf6b-dba7-4905-5187-08d7d623e1a0")
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "then":true
        }
      ],
      "default":false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You code sample is not clear. It's hard to read. Please remove those extra spaces